# How to ensure equal margins using Angular Material? (md-grid-list md-grid-tile md-rowspan)

Tags: css, angularjs, flexbox, material-design, angular-material

Here is an example on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ORajwo).

I'm setting `md-row-height="30px"` and then calculating `md-rowspan` so that it is equal to the number of elements + 1. *(plus one for the header)*

```
<md-grid-list  md-cols="1" md-cols-gt-md="3" md-cols-gt-sm="2" md-row-height="30px" md-gutter="5px">
  <md-grid-tile ng-class="tile.className" ng-repeat="tile in vm.tiles" md-rowspan="{{1 + (tile.subItems.length)}}">

    <div layout="column" layout-align="start center">
       <h3>{{ tile.title }}</h3>
       <div ng-repeat="item in tile.subItems">
         {{ item.title }}
       </div>
    </div>

  </md-grid-tile>
</md-grid-list>
```

**The margin is not equal:**
[image]

When inspecting the DOM I see plenty of calculations:
[image]

I tried a different approach using `layout="row"` - [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YGRGga) - but the tiles have equal height *(they don't fill the space efficiently)*

---

All in all I think I'm pretty close, I just need to ensure that each tile has the same margins regardless the number of items that sit inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `layout-fill` - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/pEQxAy)

Markup

```
<div layout="column" layout-align="start center" layout-fill>
   <h3 class="height30">{{ tile.title }}</h3>
   <div class="height30" ng-repeat="item in tile.subItems">
     {{ item.title }}
   </div>
</div>
```

From the [docs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/options):

[image]

Comment: Can I have the link to CodePen please? *(it seems like it is missing now)*

Comment: Magic. Are you working near Camden? My office is near London Bridge so I can take Northern Line... I'd love to see the stalls and all the creativity of craftsman and makers, potentially leading to a pint with you :)